# Kotlin: how to have abstract values as default arguments for abstract functions?

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

I have a sealed class that represents my screen states, and the different screen states are data classes, since I want to be able to copy them while changing just one value.

Unfortunately Kotlin doesn't support sealed data classes, so I am trying as close as possible to simulate this behavior:

```
sealed class ScreenState {
    abstract val item: DTOPurchasableItem
    abstract val balance: String?
    abstract fun copyScreenState(item: DTOPurchasableItem = item, balance: String? = balance): ScreenState

    data class NotEnoughMoney(override val item: DTOPurchasableItem, override val balance: String?) : ScreenState() {
        override fun copyScreenState(item: DTOPurchasableItem, balance: String?): ScreenState = copy(item = item, balance = balance)

    }

    data class ItemAlreadyOwned(override val item: DTOPurchasableItem, override val balance: String?) : ScreenState() {
        override fun copyScreenState(item: DTOPurchasableItem, balance: String?): ScreenState = copy(item = item, balance = balance)

    }
}
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work because the IDE accuses "item" and "balance" of not being initialized:

[image]

That doesn't make a lot of sense because whenever the abstract function would be invoked,  the "item" and "balance" attributes would have been initialized already...

I want to be able to:

```
val screenState = ScreenState.NotEnoughMoney(item = generateItem(), "2000")
val newState = screenState.copyScreenState(balance = "100") // it would therefore "reuse" the item that already existed, implicitly, without me need to pass it as argument.
```

Any way to achieve this? Important to note that some screen states have more arguments that belong just to those states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your parameters and properties have the same names. The `item` you're trying to use to initialize the parameter is the parameter itself, not the property. Prepend with `this.` to specify you want the property, since it is in an outer scope.

```
abstract fun copyScreenState(item: DTOPurchasableItem = this.item, balance: String? = this.balance): ScreenState
```

As for why it interprets it this way, allowing parameters to reference parameters before the function is invoked, it's because default parameter expressions can reference preceding parameters:

```
abstract fun foo(bar: String, baz: Int = bar.length)
```

So when you use the name of a parameter, it resolves to the parameter first before any property of the class with matching name. And your error is because you were accessing that parameter in its own expression.

Comment: Awesome! That was it! Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!